# How should I template this svg snippet?

Tags: c#, html, css, templates, svg

I need to make a template where I will be inserting new values for the coordinates below by finding special tags and replacing the values.

I have given a SVG and below is a small snippet of what I need to change so that I can template/add placeholders since the values below will be dynamic.

```
<g id="Layer_1">
    <g id="shape1">
        <polygon class="poly1" points="6.7,105.4 -19.2,190.5 -20.4,123.5 1.6,143.6 "/>
    </g>
    <polygon id="shape2" class="poly1" points="-20.9,300.3 -37.7,103.3 -10.9,204.3 -0.1,233.6"/>
    <circle id="circleSolid" class="poly2" cx="6.7" cy="306.1" r="10.3"/>
    <g id="circleDashed">
        <circle class="poly3" cx="2.6" cy="304.7" r="10.3"/>
    </g>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 -40.7301 191.3002)" class="poly1 poly3 poly4">Poly1</text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 -40.7302 200.3002)" class="poly1 poly3 poly4">Poly2</text>
</g>
<g id="Layer_7">
    <line id="newShape1" class="poly5" x1="-30.7" y1="170.7" x2="12.2" y2="171.7"/>
    <line id="newShape2" class="poly5" x1="-11.5" y1="160.7" x2="0.1" y2="200.3"/>
</g>>
```

I am wondering I can't just add `[x1]` tag for example below in the html tag for templating. Should I just use the classes instead to insert the new dynamic values? How should I go about templating SVG drawing?

I will be inserting the new values dynamically in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use the C# function `String.Format()` which will take in your string and replace any variables in the string with the actual text in out.

For Example:

```
string name = "Scott";
string output = String.Format("Hello {0}", name); ///outputs Hello Scott
```

So if you wanted to generate your circle element in SVG, you would have code like this:

```
string cx = '6.7';
string cy = '306.1';
string r = 10.3';
string result = String.Format("<circle id="circleSolid" class="poly2" cx="{0}" cy="{1}" r="{2}"/>", cx, cy, r);
```

which would output the follow:

```
<circle id="circleSolid" class="poly2" cx="6.7" cy="306.1" r="10.3"/>
```

- [String.Format - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: My only concern is with String.Format is that if I have a huge string file, that might not the best approach. That's why I was thinking about template and find and replace the values inside of String.Format().